# How to get coordinates from a R plotly figure

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, shinyjs

I have been struggling like mad to solve an apparently basic question.
Imagine you have a scatter plot, with say ... 10 markers. 
I suppose this plot has been generated using plotly within a Shiny environment.

One can easily get the coordinates of these markers using the `event_data("plotly_click")` code.

Now imagine you do not need the coordinates of these markers, but the coordinates generated by a mouse click but precisely where no marker exists (for example because you would like to set a new marker exactly there, and you would like to re-use the information coming from that mouse click).

I cannot obtain such a behavior using `onclick()`, or whatever.

Any idea ?

Comment: Do you need the relative Plotly coordinates, i.e. the ones you see at the axis? or just the point where the user clicked in order to create a new SVG element? Do you want to add your point to the Plotly data?

Comment: Actually I would like to add a new point where the user clicked and to be able to use the coordinates to process a new computation. 
Any soLuton for doing so would be really appreciated.
Thx

Comment: To be more direct, I need the relative Plotly coordinates as seen at the axis.

Comment: That's a tricky one. The screen coordinates are relatively easy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could add a D3 event listener to your plot

```
Plotly.d3.select('.plotly').on('click', function(d, i) {})
```

and then

- retrieve the relative x and y values based on the click position (`d3.event.layerX` resp. `layerY`)
- adjusting for the relative graph position (`document.getElementsByClassName('bg')[0].attributes['x']`)
- and finally calculating the new values based on the axis ranges (`myPlot.layout.xaxis.range[0]`)

The new `x` and `y` value are then pushed to the existing graph

```
Plotly.extendTraces(myPlot, {
      x: [[x]],
      y: [[y]]
    }, [1]);
```

**Complete R code**

```
library("plotly")
library("htmlwidgets")

p <- plot_ly(x = c( -2, 0, 2 ),y = c( -2, 1, 2), type = 'scatter' ,mode = 'lines+markers') %>% 
  add_trace(x=c(-1,0.4,2),y=c(2, 0, -1),type='scatter',mode='lines+markers') %>% 
  layout(hovermode='closest')
javascript <- "
var myPlot = document.getElementsByClassName('plotly')[0];
Number.prototype.between = function (min, max) {
  return this >= min && this <= max;
};

Plotly.d3.select('.plotly').on('click', function(d, i) {
  var e = Plotly.d3.event;
  var bg = document.getElementsByClassName('bg')[0];
  var x = ((e.layerX - bg.attributes['x'].value + 4) / (bg.attributes['width'].value)) * (myPlot.layout.xaxis.range[1] - myPlot.layout.xaxis.range[0]) + myPlot.layout.xaxis.range[0];
    var y =((e.layerY - bg.attributes['y'].value + 4) / (bg.attributes['height'].value)) * (myPlot.layout.yaxis.range[0] - myPlot.layout.yaxis.range[1]) + myPlot.layout.yaxis.range[1]
  if (x.between(myPlot.layout.xaxis.range[0], myPlot.layout.xaxis.range[1]) && 
y.between(myPlot.layout.yaxis.range[0], myPlot.layout.yaxis.range[1])) {
    Plotly.extendTraces(myPlot, {
      x: [[x]],
      y: [[y]]
    }, [1]);
  }
});"
p <- htmlwidgets::prependContent(p, onStaticRenderComplete(javascript), data=list(''))
p
```

---

**Interactive Javascript example**

```js
var traces = [{
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
  mode: 'markers',
  type: 'scatter'
}];

traces.push({
  x: [2, 3, 4, 5],
  y: [16, 5, 11, 9],
  mode: 'markers',
  type: 'scatter'
});

traces.push({
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [12, 9, 15, 12],
  mode: 'markers',
  type: 'scatter'
});

traces.push({
  x: [],
  y: [],
  mode: 'lines+markers',
  type: 'scatter'
});

var myPlot = document.getElementById('myPlot')
Plotly.newPlot('myPlot', traces, {hovermode: 'closest'});

Number.prototype.between = function(min, max) {
  return this >= min && this <= max;
};

Plotly.d3.select(".plotly").on('click', function(d, i) {
  var e = Plotly.d3.event;
  var bg = document.getElementsByClassName('bg')[0];
  var x = ((e.layerX - bg.attributes['x'].value + 4) / (bg.attributes['width'].value)) * (myPlot.layout.xaxis.range[1] - myPlot.layout.xaxis.range[0]) + myPlot.layout.xaxis.range[0];
  var y = ((e.layerY - bg.attributes['y'].value + 4) / (bg.attributes['height'].value)) * (myPlot.layout.yaxis.range[0] - myPlot.layout.yaxis.range[1]) + myPlot.layout.yaxis.range[1]
  if (x.between(myPlot.layout.xaxis.range[0], myPlot.layout.xaxis.range[1]) &&
    y.between(myPlot.layout.yaxis.range[0], myPlot.layout.yaxis.range[1])) {
    Plotly.extendTraces(myPlot, {
      x: [
        [x]
      ],
      y: [
        [y]
      ]
    }, [3]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="myPlot" style="width:100%;height:100%"></div>
```

---

**Shiny example**

```
library(shiny)
library("plotly")
library("htmlwidgets")

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
   javascript <- "
function(el, x){
  Number.prototype.between = function (min, max) {
   return this >= min && this <= max;
  };

  Plotly.d3.select('.plotly').on('click', function(d, i) {
  var e = Plotly.d3.event;
  var bg = document.getElementsByClassName('bg')[0];
  var x = ((e.layerX - bg.attributes['x'].value + 4) / (bg.attributes['width'].value)) * (el.layout.xaxis.range[1] - el.layout.xaxis.range[0]) + el.layout.xaxis.range[0];
  var y =((e.layerY - bg.attributes['y'].value + 4) / (bg.attributes['height'].value)) * (el.layout.yaxis.range[0] - el.layout.yaxis.range[1]) + el.layout.yaxis.range[1]
  if (x.between(el.layout.xaxis.range[0], el.layout.xaxis.range[1]) && y.between(el.layout.yaxis.range[0], el.layout.yaxis.range[1])) {
    Plotly.extendTraces(el, {
     x: [[x]],
     y: [[y]]
    }, [1]);
  }
});
}"
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(x = c( -2, 0, 2 ),y = c( -2, 1, 2), type = 'scatter' ,mode = 'lines+markers') %>% 
    add_trace(x=c(-1,0.4,2),y=c(2, 0, -1),type='scatter',mode='lines+markers') %>% 
    layout(hovermode='closest') %>% onRender(javascript)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you Maximilian, it works perfectly ... but not in a Shiny environment. I believe this is due to the fact that prependContent() is not supported within a Shiny widget rendering content.

Comment: For shiny you would need to wrap the JS code with `function(el, x){ ... }` and use `%>% onRender(javascript)` where you call your plotly function. -- See updated answer

Comment: It works perfectly. Maximilian : just one word for all this => brilliant. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The solution by Maximilian does not work on Plotly.js versions later than 1.42.0. Trying to fetch

```
var bg = document.getElementsByClassName('bg')[0];
```

returns undefined. The solution works using version 1.41.3.

This answer is most likely more suited to be a comment but my reputation does not meet the minimum requirement of 50.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Just checked with latest Plotly version in R and the code still works, same with Plotly.js outside of Stackoverflow. Seems to be an issue of how the code is embedded in Stackoverflow.