# how to get the coordinates of the drawn figure in plotly

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I would like to get the coordinates of the drawn rectangle in a separate variable, also I would like the coordinates to change if I resize the rectangle.

```
library(plotly)

x <- 1:50
y <- rnorm(50)

fig <- plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
fig <- config(fig,modeBarButtonsToAdd = list('drawrect'))

fig
```

[image]

[There is a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46157790/how-to-get-coordinates-from-a-r-plotly-figure), but none of the solutions worked for me, those solutions must be outdated by now

Comment: You want that on the R console? Or in a Shiny app?

Comment: @Stéphane Laurent 
 To be honest, I'm interested in both options, if such exist.

That is, I will accept any of the solutions as an answer, but I'm interested in both options

Comment: Only possible with Shiny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `plotly_relayout` event in a Shiny app.

```r
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons("plotType", "Plot Type:", choices = c("ggplotly", "plotly")),
  plotlyOutput("plot"),
  verbatimTextOutput("relayout")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  nms <- row.names(mtcars)
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    p <- if (identical(input$plotType, "ggplotly")) {
      ggplotly(
        ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt, customdata = nms)) + geom_point()
      )
    } else {
      plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~wt, customdata = nms)
    }
    p %>% 
      layout(dragmode = "select") %>%
      config(modeBarButtonsToAdd = list("drawrect"))
  })
  
  output$relayout <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_relayout")
    if (is.null(d)) "Rectangle coordinates will appear here" else d
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: marvelously....